# Extracting links from xml using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have an xml page with the following structure:

```
<item>
  <pubDate>Sat, 12 Dec 2015 16:35:00 GMT</pubDate>
  <title>
   some text
  </title>
  <link>
     http://www.example.com/index.xml
  </link>
  ...
```

And I would like to extract and **follow** links within the `<links>` tag.

I only have the default code for this:

```
start_urls = ['example.com/example.xml']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="example.com"),
          callback='parse_item',),
)
```

But I don't know how to follow "text" tags. I've actually tried the `linkextractor` `tags='links'` option, but to no avail. The log effectively goes to the page, gets a 200 reply, but does not get any links .

Comment: use `restrict_xpaths='//link'` in `LinkExtractor` to get the links from the link tag

Comment: @Vaulstein: thanks, but no luck. If I do `response.xpath("//item/link/text()").extract()'` at the scrapy console, it does return the links' text, but if it's doing that in the main code, it's definitely not following them.

Comment: The key problem here is that the links are *inside the elements texts* and not the attributes. Link Extractors extract the links from the `href` attribute by default and, I think, they are designed to grab the links from the attributes, but I'm pretty sure you can point to the texts instead.

Comment: @alecxe: I thought so too, I tried using the `tags` argument in `LinkExtractor`, but I also failed to get the list of links

Comment: @DervinThunk I'll definitely take a look later if nobody would provide a working answer before. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe: no, thank *you*!

Comment: @DervinThunk by the way, is this an XML feed?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key problem here is that this is not a regular HTML input, but an XML feed and the links are *inside the elements texts* and not the attributes. I think you just need the [`XMLFeedSpider`](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=rule#xmlfeedspider-example) here:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider

class MySpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = ['url_here']

    itertag = "item"

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        for link in node.xpath(".//link/text()").extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(link.strip(), callback=self.parse_link)

    def parse_link(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use xml.etree library.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET



res = '''
<item>
  <pubDate>Sat, 12 Dec 2015 16:35:00 GMT</pubDate>
  <title>
   some text
  </title>
  <link>
     http://www.example.com/index.xml
  </link>
</item>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(res)
results = root.findall('.//link')
for res in results:
    print res.text
```

The output will be as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/index.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I do get the links, I just fail to follow them. besides, i see you're using lxml, and I'd like to stay within the scrapy library for learning purposes.